# How to install llvm-14

Tags: clang, llvm

I had llvm-14 before but something really weird happened, but it got removed. I tried `sudo apt install llvm-14`

but I get the error:

```
llvm-14 : Depende: llvm-14-runtime (= 1:14.0.6~++20221030064722+f28c006a5895-1~exp1~20221030064759.169) pero no va a instalarse
           Depende: llvm-14-linker-tools (= 1:14.0.6~++20221030064722+f28c006a5895-1~exp1~20221030064759.169) pero no va a instalarse
           Depende: libllvm14 pero no va a instalarse
           Recomienda: llvm-14-dev pero no va a instalarse
```

(sorry it's in Spanish, it basically tells that those deps are missing and they will not be installed)

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the package and install again.

```
sudo apt-get remove && sudo apt install llvm-14
```